# D3 treemap colors mix up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, treemap

I have made a D3 treemap based on this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582. My version also shows the children after clicking the treemap or button.

The size/count changefunction doesn't work as it should: I get double nodes, the backgroundcolors mix up and there are divs without a backgroundcolor.

```
color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(colorDomainArr) //colorDomainArr = [0,1,2,3]
    .range([ 
        "#b1e1d7", "#c1e7df", "#d1ede6", "#e1f3ee", //lichtblauw
        "#688ea3", "#87a4b5", "#a5bac7", "#c3d0d9", //donkerblauw
        "#cbb84c", "#d7c671", "#e3d494", //"#eee2b7", //geel
        "#b9c2c1", "#ced4d3", "#e3e6e6", //"#f8f8f8", //grijs
    ]);
```

It used to work, but not after I fixed another similar colorproblem.

I haven't changed the change() function.

I've tried adding

```
node.style("background", function(d) {
    return d.children && d.depth != ondiepst && d.depth != ondiepst-1 ? color(d.name) : null
})
```

Color is also done by

```
d3.selectAll(".BG").style("background", function(d) { return color(d.name) });
```

1. In the first view everything goes well
   [image: In the first view everything goes well]
2. Click on 'Laat alles zien'-button: Colors mix up
   [image: Click on 'Laat alles zien'-button: Colors mix up]
3. Click on 'count' radio button: no background color on some nodes
   [image: Click on 'count' radio button: no background color on some nodes]
4. Click on 'Originele weergave'-button: it seems like everything is well, but we see the 'size' version instead of the 'count' version.
   [image: Click on 'Originele weergave'-button: it seems like everything is well, but we see the 'size' version instead of the 'count' version.]
5. Click on 'size' radio button: three/four times double nodes instead of original view
   [image: Click on 'size' radio button: three/four times double nodes instead of original view]

The jsfiddle doesn't work as it does locally, but it shows my problem and code.
https://jsfiddle.net/zjx967g4/

Comment: You can post a link to your picture and someone (I for example) can edit it into your question.

Comment: first numbers correspondent to my numbered list in my question
1.  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UH2p7.jpg
 2. [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lgVa1.jpg
 3.  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VwbTt.jpg
4. [1] again
 5.  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JNT5p.jpg